# MySQL prevent inserting duplicate field

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to prevent an insertion of a row with the same field value, **where the field ISN'T a key**.

There could be two types of insertions in my case: The first is run by a script, the second is by some DAO in a server. As far as the script is concerned, the `username` field is unique, However, the server shouldn't prevent multiple `username` - This is why I can't have a unique index on the `username` field.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO test(user_name) VALUES ('alex');
```

I tried suggested answer and it didn't work.

```
INSERT INTO test(user_name) VALUES ('alex') WHERE user_name NOT IN ('alex');
```

Comment: Show some sample data/table structure and what the output should look like.

Comment: You have enough reputation to know how to ask a good question...

Comment: Are you using your brother's account to ask a question?

Comment: What isn't clear about the question :O? It looks pretty clear to me..

Comment: Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output. What you're doing is asking for code, SO isn't a free coding service, you need to try yourself and ask for help if you get  stuck.

Comment: Well, this IS a technical question! The answer is obviously code..I'm asking a usecase which I researched and found no results. I described all the necessary parts. I don't understand what is missing.

Comment: I added queries to be more specific. @nick it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I used this approach:

```
INSERT INTO test(user_name) 
    SELECT ('alex' ) WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from test where user_name='alex');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need [Insert Ignore](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html):

> If you use the IGNORE modifier, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that
>   duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table
>   causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With
>   IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors
>   generate warnings instead.

If there is the same value it is going to ignore it.

You might can also use `Replace` or `Insert Into ... on Duplicate Key` it depends on what do you want to achieve exactly.

Here is a good post regarding to this question: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/

**UPDATE:**
As you updated your question I have to update my answer as well.
Could be the username `Unique`? In that case `Insert Ignore` and `Replace` could work as well.

**UPDATE2:**

In last resort you can create a procedure like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertUserName;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertUserName(IN name VARCHAR(255))
 BEGIN
 If NOT EXISTS (select user_name from test where user_name=name limit 1) then
 BEGIN
    insert into test (`user_name`) values (name);
 END;   
 END IF;
 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

You can call it like:

```
call InsertUserName('alex');
```

If `alex` is exist in the table it won't add it if there is no `alex` it will insert it.

BUT please at least add a normal not unique key on the `user_name` column, it will improve the performance a lot.

Comment: I can't use an index or keys. This is a field without a key.. and I can't add it

Comment: You need at least a key on it because every single time when you insert a new name you have to check if that name is exist. If there is no index on `user_name` column every single time it is a full table scan, which is slow and not good for performance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But this is a simplification of a more complex use case. These are the restriction I have.

Comment: I would prefer not a stored procedure solution

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to tell MySQL that you would like it to prohibit two rows with the same value in `user_name` while still using the `id` column as the primary key, then the solution is a UNIQUE INDEX:

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX <IndexName> ON test(user_name)
```

That said, if both `id` and `user_name` are unique, then `id` is serving no purpose and you should consider abandoning it in favor of just `user_name` (there are some reasons that might make this improvement less feasible, but you don't mention any of them in your question).

Comment: I can't use an index

Comment: Why can you not use an index?

Comment: Because there isn't a clear distinct key. My example is simplified. These are the restriction I have

Comment: Please state the *actual* problem you have.  If there is a clear statement of a column or set of columns that must be unique, you can solve the problem with a UNIQUE INDEX.  If there is no clear statement of what "unique" means, you cannot solve the problem because the problem is not clearly stated.  If you have a clear statement of the problem but are prohibited from applying declarative DDL statements to the database you need to solve the problem in the code that runs the INSERT statement (eg, prechecking for the existing record).

Comment: I added the reason for these restriction

Comment: You cannot solve this problem using only the `INSERT` statement.  You must nest the `INSERT` inside some kind of check for the existence of the value you're concerned about.  You can do that in the scripting language you're using, or you can create a stored procedure in MySQL that allows `IF/THEM` logic and call that stored procedure.

Comment: I found the way to do the logic. See my answer